# Qimage: out of memory, returning null image

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qgraphicsview, qimage

I am writing a code to show a video in a graphicsView QObject. It goes like this:

```
void MainWindow::UpdateVideo()
{
    cap >> frame;
    cvtColor(frame, frame,CV_BGR2RGB);
    QImage Qframe = QImage((uchar*) frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    QPointer<QGraphicsScene> VideoScene = new QGraphicsScene;
    VideoScene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Qframe));
    ui->VideoView->setScene(VideoScene);
    ui->VideoView->show();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    cap.open("test1.mpg");
    if(!cap.isOpened())
       cout<<"CANNOT OPEN FILE"<<endl; //or you can put some error message
    QPointer<QTimer> UpdateVideo = new QTimer;
    connect(UpdateVideo, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(UpdateVideo()));
    UpdateVideo->start(10);
}
```

As you can see, the slot on_pushButton_2_clicked() will call slot UpdateVideo() with the timer every 10ms after the first click. I want to get the video to displays flawlessly but after a few seconds the following error appears on the application output of qt creator:

> Qimage: out of memory, returning null image.

And then the graphicsView frame goes blank. Can you tell me where is the memory leak?

Comment: I wonder, what happens when you are assigning your timer. Will it always be deleted afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that [QPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qpointer.html) does what you think. You are constantly allocating new `QGraphicScene`s. That's why you are running out of resources.

1. The scene should be held by the window or outside.
2. The `QGraphicsPixmapItem*` returned by `addPixmap` should be remebered.
3. The `setPixmap (const QPixmap  &pixmap )` method of `QGraphicsPixmapItem` should be called to update the image.

For example:

```
class PixmapView
: public QGraphicsView
{
public:
    QPlotView( QGraphicsScene *scene) 
    : QGraphicsView( scene )
    , pixmap( 256, 256 )
    {
        pixmapItem = scene->addPixmap( pixmap );
        buffer.resize( 256*256*4 );
        startTimer( 100 );
    }

   void timerEvent( QTimerEvent* )
   {
       QImage image( &buffer[0], 256, 256, QImage::Format_ARGB32 );
       pixmapItem->setPixmap(  QPixmap::fromImage( image ) );
   }

private:
    std::vector<uchar> buffer;
    QPixmap pixmap;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem* pixmapItem;
};
```

Edit:

You are also constantly allocating new `QTimer`s. A single timer should be a member of the window as it needs to survive the end of the method.

Comment: Thanks, let me check and I'll get back to you.

Comment: That definition, std::unique_ptr<uchar[]> buffer; does not work for me, i get ISO C++ forbids declaration of "unique_ptr" with no type.

Comment: Then just use a std::vector<uchar> or use a uchar* and delete[] it in the destructor.

Comment: Al the compiler complains about QPlotView with the same error, can you explain a little more your example?

Comment: What don't you understand? It is just an example illustrating points 1-3.

Comment: Thanks I solved my problem with your method and some slight modifications.