# After loading a image around 500 times , this error shows in visual studio QImage: out of memory, returning null image

Tags: c++, qt, qimage, qbytearray

I want to show a image on qt label. I am getting image data in the form of `QByteArray` and I am loading it into label.
Below is the code :

defined in constructor

```
QPixmap *pixmapTest;
pixmapTest  = NULL;
```

the following code is in a function which is getting called multiple times :

```
    RequestCompleted(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
if(pixmapTest){
    qDebug()<<"delete showImage Pixmap Object";
    delete pixmapTest;
    pixmapTest = NULL;
}
pixmapTest = new QPixmap();
QByteArray jpegData = reply->readAll();
pixmapTest->loadFromData(jpegData);
ui.qtLabel->setPixmap(*pixmapTest);
}
```

After calling this function for around 500 times I am getting this error

```
QImage: out of memory, returning null image.
```

I am not getting what is the error in the above code. Can someone please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like you are leaking memory. Probably `jpegData`...

Comment: Create a new pixmap object every time seems strange, best to create the `pixmapTest`  once and then just call `loadFromData`. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316008/qimage-out-of-memory-returning-null-image

Comment: i assume you need to do a delete(pixMapTest) at some point. Or put it in a smart pointer like shared_ptr

Answer (score 1):

First off allocating and de-allocating memory for a variable (`pixmapTest`) in a function that gets called many times doesn't make sense enough. You should allocate the memory first and once all is done de-allocate it. For example:

```
pixmapTest = new QPixmap();

for(size_t i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    // Call that function
}

delete pixmapTest;
```

Apart from this, it sounds like your app is leaking memory. Note that by deleting the `pixmapTest`, you're not deleteing the memory `jpegData` points to. Therefore, in each function call you should take care of the memory to which `jpegData` points.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you're not freeing the `reply` itself.

There's also no need to store the pixmap, nor to manage it through a pointer. Keep it by value, and assign new value each time you receive a reply.

E.g.:

```
class MyClass : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  Ui::MyClass ui;

  explicit MyClass(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {
    ui.setupUi(this);
  }

  Q_SLOT void requestCompleted(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    QPixmap pix;
    pix.loadFromData(reply->readAll());
    ui.qtLabel->setPixmap(pix);
    reply->deleteLater();
  }
};
```

Comment: on doing this I am getting these errors 
Pixmap is a null pixmap
look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276248/getting-pixmap-is-a-null-pixmap-on-calling-a-function-500-times]

Comment: Well, perhaps the data you receive is not in the right format. How could we know any of that? It's on you to check it and ensure the code makes sense. You have to understand the problem well enough to know what questions to ask, not merely to say "hey, it doesn't work".

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion. I will keep in mind this statement before asking the next question.